# asp.net mvc4 url rewrite for seo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

Url rewrite code to use to for asp.net MVC4; I use to App_Start/RouteConfig.cs in the code down.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "subjectSefLink",
url: "{controller}/{seo}/{page}",
defaults: new
{
    controller = "subject",
    action = "Index",
    seo = UrlParameter.Optional,
    page = UrlParameter.Optional
});
```

I use the Controller;

```
 public class SubjectController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(string seo, int page)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

but does not work; The output of the code = 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `int page` variable as `nullable`. As in routing, you have declared `page` variable as `Optional`. So, the action method in controller should be like this

```
public class SubjectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string seo, int? page)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```